# What is the difference between api.branch.io and api2.branch.io?

Tags: php, laravel, branch.io

Currently in my project(Laravel), api.branch.io/v1/url has been used, but it is throwing as failed to connect to port 443 after few seconds.

{"message":"cURL error 28: Failed to connect to api.branch.io port 443 after 75265 ms: Timeout was reached (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for [https://api.branch.io/v1/url","payload":{...}](https://api.branch.io/v1/url%22,%22payload%22:%7B...%7D)

If i try to change it to api2.branch.io/v1/url then it is creating a deep link. So to migrate from api to api2, is there any document to follow or can we directly change the URL.

Can someone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

We are reaching out to let you know that Branch will be removing support for our v1 Events API endpoint on September 4, 2022. The v1 Events API endpoint will no longer function after this date and this will impact your app experience.

Branch highly recommends you update your app with the latest version of our API to avoid any impact to your app experience. Many of our latest features and products are not supported with the v1 Events API.

Here is a sample list of the features and products that are not supported by v1 Event API:

SkAdNetwork
Facebook Advanced Matching
Snapchat Advanced Matching
Google Ads Attribution & Reporting (without Device IDs)
Android Privacy Sandbox Attribution Reporting API (when launched)
Next Steps:

Confirm which API version you have installed in your app.
If your app is utilizing the following methods, please update to our current APIs as detailed here.

```
sendCommerceEvent()
```

userCompletedAction()
Branch.track()

Please ensure you make any necessary updates by September 4, 2023 to avoid disruption to your app experience.

Branch is here to support you during this transition, just reach out to your Branch Account Team or support@branch.io with any questions.

The Branch Team